# How to change the owner of perforce workspace?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I cloned a workspace in perforce from other credentials (as i was having some issue with my account back then due to permissions). Now i have the relevant permissions so want to change the owner of that workspace.
In p4v tool, I logged in from the account through which the workspace was created and i tried to change the owner in the advanced options but it gives an error "**Client specification failed: You can't create another user's workspace.**"
Any ideas on how can we change the owner ?

Comment: Did you try claiming ownership of the workspace while logged in as yourself?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using the command line as it's much faster

```
p4 client <workspace name>
```

Then change the Owner: to the one you want, save and you're done.